# Range input showing a set value

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

Whenever a number is chosen in the Range Input, show me a certain pre-set value. In that code I have now it's almost there, but instead of calculating (adding, multiplying or anything else) I want a number that will be defined by me.

**Examples:**

*If the Range Input is set to 12, then Shipping - $ 22.00 will appear.*

If the Range Input is set to 42, then: Shipping - $ 136.00 will appear.

There is no rule and no definite calculation, I need to create all the options. From option 1 to 65, that is, I will create 65 defined values for each number in the Range Input.

I hope you can understand, I tried to explain the best! Haha

Thank you for your help!

```js
<script>
    var val = document.getElementById("valR").value;

    // Caculate your price from the chosen value
    var price = Number(val) + 22;

    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = val;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "$ " + price;

    function showVal(newVal) {
        var newprice = Number(newVal) + 22; // Caculate the price from the chosen value
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = newVal;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "$ " + newprice;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<input id="valR" type="range" min="1" max="65" value="0" step="1" oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)" />

<span id="range">1</span>
<div id="money"></div>
```

Comment: so when you slider to for example "6" then it will have its own case function()? like 6+22?

Comment: You mean something like this, where each price has a specific shipping value? https://jsfiddle.net/7w0aumfq/

Comment: @yuriy636 yes man! thanks! As I would put the following tag: oninput = "showVal (this.value)"
I tested it and when the values ​​change it appears: undefined
In the way, do you understand? When I stop it, the normal value appears, but as I press the mouse and slide it appears undefined. But I really appreciate the help! Thank you so!

Comment: @yuriy636 another question... sorry! Have a way to do by button? So I select the normal number in the Range and then click the button and the values ​​will appear.